# How to restart flutter app in docker container?

Tags: docker, flutter, docker-compose

**I am trying to restart flutter application running in Docker.**

I specified **stdin_open** and **tty** to **true** in docker-compose.yml file

- This is the only one place in docker-compose.yml where I've specified stdin and tty.

  ```
  app:
    build:
      context: app
    restart: always
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./app:/build
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    env_file:
      - ./env/flutter.env
    command: >
      sh -c "flutter pub get
      && flutter run -d web-server --web-port 8080 --web-hostname 0.0.0.0"
    depends_on:
      - server
  ```

[image: Running flutter web with docker-compose]

On the screen above it is visible that I cannot restart an application this way.

I have to do it manually by using command: **docker-compose up --detach --build**

**Is there any way I can interact with this container and restart app by pressing "R" ?**

Comment: The `docker-compose` command you show is the normal way to do it.

Comment: Okay, I understand. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
docker attach <container>
```

Press `R`. Press `Ctrl-P` `Ctrl-Q` to detach.

Comment: It doesn't work either. Same result as before

Comment: @Wiktor can you provide some hello-world code so I can run flutter myself?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/qEAEcECN
This is the simplest one main file, but you need a lot of more files to build it. With flutter sdk, you can run `flutter create <name>` to create a ready to run flutter template.

Comment: @Wiktor I tried many times to make it work with `docker-compose` but failed. It seems the only thing it forwards are process signals. On the other hand the solution I posted above worked well: https://i.imgur.com/LmBCXuy.png . I tried several launch configurations and there was no problem with restart by pressing R.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. It works, that's right. I had to attach it before it started running in the browser. Thank you very much